# what is the first step of ssh copy execute in terminal?

Tags: zsh, glob, scp

I am using this command to copy file from remote server to local machine:

```
scp -r app:/home/dolphin/model* .
```

In bash it works fine.In zsh it throw this error:`zsh: no matches found: app:/home/dolphin/model*`.I am searching from Google and understand the bash and zsh have different rule of glob.Here is my question:

- what is the execute step detail of this command?
- anyone could tell me the shell how to execute the command,the first step is echo the path of this command?

I could use -v(verbose) to see the scp execute process.

Comment: Seems like Zsh is failing to grep non-existent files while Bash just passes the unglobbed string to the program.

Comment: any detail message,how to see the parse procedure,it it possible to see?@Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with Zsh, but as far as I can say, Bash will pass the original string to the program as an argument if nothing is globbed, while it appears that Zsh complains in this case.

To ensure the "unglobbed" string is passed as an argument to scp(1), you can escape the asterisk:

```
scp -r app:/home/dolphin/model\* .
                              ^^
```

Comment: It is any possible to see the procedure of parsing or understand the procedure?@iBug

Comment: @Dolphin Maybe you'll need to understand how Zsh works. This issue is not related to `scp` because Zsh is complaining about globbing failure, at which point it has just parsed the command line and applying expansion. Online documentations might be helpful - I'm not aware of any built-in way to inspect each step that the shell performs before actually running the command.